# Does Anyone know which all fields in an X.509 certificate is used for authenticating the digital signature?

Tags: java, c, validation, certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying validate an X.509 certificate received over a network. I have understood that the digital signature is created by creating a message digest of the fields(don't know which fields) in the signature and then encrypting it using the CA(Certificate Authority) private Key.We can validate the certificate by decrypting the digital signature using CA public key and comparing it with the message digest of the certificate fields.

I'm stuck at this point as I don't know which all fields I should take to create the message digest for the validation. Can somebody please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a glance at [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1.1.3) it appears to be the whole `tbsCertificate` field.

> [...] a digital signature computed upon
> the ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate.  The ASN.1 DER encoded
> tbsCertificate is used as the input to the signature function.